# IFTTT - Exclude Twitter Retweets

Tags: twitter, discord, ifttt

I am using IFTTT (https://ifttt.com/) to fetch Twitter Tweets using the search function with **#hashtag** to my Discord server. Is there any way to exclude Retweets? Currently the whole server gets spammed with popular tweets, since it also fetches all the Retweets.

Tried studying Twitter API (https://developer.twitter.com/) and using stuff like **-RT**, **exclude:replies** and **exclude:retweets**. None of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like **-RT** does work after all. I used quotation marks (as shown in IFTTT's own example) which broke the search function. Instead of using **"#hashtag -RT"** to fetch all the Tweets without Retweets, you should use **#hashtag -RT**, without quotation marks. Otherwise it won't fetch the Tweets at all.